# MVC Generic Repository Filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, generics

I have multiple Entity Framework classes which have some identical properties such as Order which is used to set the display order.

An example EF partial class:

```
[Table("Feature")]
public partial class Feature
{
    public long ID { get; set; }

    public long AppID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(15)]
    public string DisplayMode { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

Other entity classes also contain the AppID property.

Is it possible in my Repository class to have a generic method to obtain the highest value of Order filtered by AppID?

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class
{
    public int NewOrderNumber(long appID)
    {
        int result = 0;

        var count = Context.Set<TEntity>().Count();

        if (count != 0)
        {
            result = (from List in Context.Set<TEntity>()
                      where List.AppID == appID
                      orderby List.Order
                      select List.Order).ToList().LastOrDefault();

            result++;
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

As it's coded, TEntity has no concept of the AppID property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add an interface

```
public interface IAppOrdered
{
   long AppID { get; }
   public int Order { get; }
}
```

Let you classes implement the interface

```
public partial class Feature : IAppOrdered
{
}
```

And then add a generic constraint to the repository class

```
public class Repository<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IAppOrdered
{
}
```

You can now access `AppId` and `Order` properties from you Repository.